# CSS and JS with strange hashed file names

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've been studying some others websites' codes and I noticed that some sites are using strange css and js file names.

Example:

```
www.website.com/js/s_bda6c508a1d8d5de14fb21f61da91512.js
www.website.com/css/6357525.css
```

Does anyone know what kind of technique is that?

Comment: Is it like that every time? or do the numbers change when you refresh the page and view the source again?

Comment: That's a hash used for cache-busting.

Comment: The site is likely using some sort of combiner/minifier, and link @SLaks said, the name is a hash used for cache-busting. Another technique includes adding a query value to the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often it's because of asset compilation by a framework.

I work with Ruby on Rails and on my dev machine my css files might be named `application.css` and `ui.css` or whatever but when rails deploys it will compile all those files into one file  with a name like:

```
 application-bec2abb573c652a8d453f24b457e389d.css
```

Which is just a stamp for my server which tells it which deploy the assets were compiled for.

It also protects against old caches as was mentioned by several others.

Answer (score 11):

That is most likely a randomly generated hash for busting your cache.

Basically, they probably combine and minify all of their JS and CSS resources so there is a single main file for each (which greatly reduces page load time due to less http requests).

Any time they run the script that compiles these files, they are given random gibberish names like that so that the next time a user visits the site, they will download the updated CSS and JS rather than their browser using the old cached version and potentially causing the page to display incorrectly (like if they used a more conventional name like `scripts.js` or `style.css`).

edit: like jesus.tesh pointed out in his comment, another very common technique for cache busting is to add a random and meaningless query value to the end of your resource href, e.g. `style.css?22137310`).

Comment: +1 for the note about the query value, which makes this answer the most worthwhile, as well as the very accurate answer. A random query string is also standard practice for Hit-O-Meters and busting the cache when testing your own files on a misconfigured web server or when accessing them via an ISP that overzealously caches.

Answer (score 0):

Its simply random file names.

Why?
The answer why to do it is very simple. Whenever your browser request content from domain (js, css, images etc) it cache the reply on your disk so next time it ask for it it will not go and download it again (HTTP status code 304) so in order to bypass the cache mechanism whenever you access the web page the site generate different file name to force the browser to download fresh copy of the file each time.